# How can I insert a new line with the indentation of the line above?

Tags: indentation

[image]

When I type `o`,  it will insert a new line, and it is exactly new line without any indentation. The cursor will go to the beginning.

How can I insert a new line with the indentation of the line above?

Comment: Have you tried `:set autoindent`?